# Finding multiple values in a string Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a three strings of categories

1. "SharePoint,Azure,IT";
2. "BizTalk,Finance";
3. "SharePoint,Finance";

I need to find a way to check if a string contains for example "SharePoint" and "IT", or "BizTalk" and "Finance".  The tests are individual strings themselces.

How would i loop through all the category strings (1 - 3) and only return the ones which have ALL instances of the souce.

i have tried the following

```
            function doesExist(source, filterArray)
        {
            var substr = filterArray.split(" ");

            jQuery.each(substr, function() {
                var filterTest = this;                              
                if(source.indexOf(filterTest) != -1 )
                {                       
                    alert("true");
                    return true;
                }else
                {   
                    alert("false");
                    return false;           
                }                                       
            });
        }
```

with little success...the code above checks one at a time rather than both so the results returned are incorrect.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Chris

UPDATE: here is a link to a work in progress version..http://www.invisiblewebdesign.co.uk/temp/filter/#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doesExist(source, filter)
{
    var sourceArray = source.split(",");
    var filterArray = filter.split(",");

    var match = true;
    $.each(filterArray, function(i, val) {
         match = match && ($.inArray(val, sourceArray) != -1);
    });
    return match;
}
```

gives `doesExist("SharePoint,Azure,IT", "SharePoint,IT")==true` but `doesExist("SharePoint,Azure,IT", "SharePoint,BizTalk")==false`.

Comment: Brilliant..that appears to work... :) i will need to do some extensive testing..however would you be able to do 2 things for me?

Comment: 1.) can you explain the code please?
2.) would this be possible for a third free text entry value?  there would be no reason not to work for another text input?  how would i add another level in basically :)  Thanks btw

Comment: I have just found that if i leave my top filter alone and only filter on teh bottom it does nothing....i think that may be to do with my crappy filter builder code lol...  (the top part of my complileFilter() method in my code online..(UPDATED ONLINE CODE)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
if(filterArray.indexOf("SharePoint") > -1 && filterArray.indexOf("IT") > -1) {
...
}
```

Comment: i think the examples that chris gave were examples. hard coding just wouldn't cut it here i'm afraid.

Comment: The filter array contains the values of SharePOint and IT etc in a CSV format.  The source contains the general categores of an item...e.g. <li rel="sharepoint azure biztalk it" class='red'><a href="#"><img src="images/sharepoint.jpg" /></a><br />Client Name</li>